# tidy eval with e.g. mtcars %>% mutate(target := log(target))

Tags: r, tidyeval

I figured this out while typing my question, but would like to see if there's a cleaner, less code way of doing what I want.

e.g. code block:

```
target <- "mpg"

# want
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(target := log(target))
```

I'd like to update mpg to be the log of mpg based on the variable target.

Looks like I got this working with:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(!! rlang::sym(target) := log(!! rlang::sym(target)))
```

That just reads as pretty repetitive. Is there a 'cleaner', less code way of achieving the same result?

I'm fond of the double curly braces `{{var}}`, no reason, they are just nicer to read imho but I couldn't get the same results when I tried:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(!! rlang::sym(target) := log({{target}}))
```

What are the various ways I can use tidyeval to mutate a field via  transformation based on a pre determined variable to define which field to be transformed, in this case the variable 'target'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `lhs` of `:=`, the string can be evaluated with just `!!`, while on the rhs, it is the value that we need, so we convert to symbol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
     mutate(!!target := log(!! rlang::sym(target)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Are double curly braces at all relevant here or do they have no place in this context?

Comment: @DougFir It is used mostly when we pass unquoted variables into a function.  It does `!! + enquo`

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate_at(target, log)
```

**2)** We can use the magrittr `%<>%` operator:

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars[[target]] %<>% log
```

**3)** Of course this is trivial in base R:

```
mtcars[[target]] <- log(mtcars[[target]])
```